# How to highlight the column that I select through a checkbox in JavaFX

Tags: css, checkbox, javafx, tableview, background-color

I've a situation like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xinrb.png)

In the moment that I select a checkbox (one or more), I want to highlight the  corresponding columns.

I'm trying this stupid and rude [solution](http://pastebin.com/ns43UwmW), but it's working only in the header of the columns.

Comment: [it's not working when I disabled checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etE3A.png)

Comment: Are they mutually exclusive check boxes?

Comment: No, I can select any checkbox.
For each selected checkbox, I want to display its corresponding column highlighted and for each deselected checkbox, I don't want display its corresponding column highlighted.

Comment: Checkbox and TableColumn are separated (look my wrong solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight an entire column, you need to use a cell factory on the column and highlight the cells. This is similar in nature to [JavaFX - Detect & highlight TableColumn being dragged onto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810408/javafx-detect-highlight-tablecolumn-being-dragged-onto), but you need to be able to highlight multiple columns. To do that, use an `ObservableSet<TableColumn<?,?>` to keep track of which columns should be highlighted, and add/remove columns to it from your checkboxes.

Here is an example, adapted from the example linked above:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TableColumnHighlightByCheckBox extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        ObservableSet<TableColumn<?,?>> highlightColumns = FXCollections.observableSet();

        table.getItems().addAll(createData());

        VBox checkBoxes = new VBox(5);
        checkBoxes.getStyleClass().add("controls");
        table.getColumns().forEach(col -> 
            checkBoxes.getChildren().add(createHighlightColumnCheckBox(col, highlightColumns)));

        table.getColumns().forEach(col -> highlightColumnWhenNeeded(col, highlightColumns));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setTop(checkBoxes);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> CheckBox createHighlightColumnCheckBox(TableColumn<S,T> column, ObservableSet<TableColumn<?,?>> highlightColumns) {


        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.textProperty().bind(column.textProperty());
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                highlightColumns.add(column);
            } else {
                highlightColumns.remove(column);
            }
        });

        return checkBox ;
    }

    private <S,T> void highlightColumnWhenNeeded(TableColumn<S,T> column, ObservableSet<TableColumn<?,?>> highlightColumns) {

        Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> currentCellFactory = column.getCellFactory() ;

        PseudoClass highlight = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight");

        column.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TableCell<S,T> cell = currentCellFactory.call(tc);
            highlightColumns.addListener((Change<? extends TableColumn<?,?>> c) -> 
                    cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlight,
                        highlightColumns.contains(column)));

            cell.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlight, highlightColumns.contains(column));

            return cell ;
        });
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    private List<Person> createData() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")     
        );
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();


        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }


        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }



        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }



        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }



        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }



        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }



        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }



        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }



        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }



        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And the stylesheet:

```css
.table-cell:highlight {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-background: yellow ;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color -fx-table-cell-border-color transparent transparent ;
}
.controls {
    -fx-padding: 10 ;
}
```

I just made the entire cell bright yellow if the column it is in is highlighted, but you can modify the stylesheet to use any style you like for highlighting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Your solution has helped me and [this is my simple solution](http://pastebin.com/2R8Sz0p5).
I'm a java beginner, can you explain me your the highlightColumnWhenNeeded method? I don't understand very well  the wildcards and generics type

Comment: `TableColumn<?,?>` just means "TableColumn of some unknown type". Since you're just storing them in a set, you don't care what type they are, so it's fine to keep that general.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
However there is a problem: after select checkbox, if I scroll table view, some row will be not highlighted. 
It's highlighted all cell only I select other checkbox... [look this video to understand the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4DnnOFIUtc).
It's a layout problem in fxml or java code?

Comment: @giuseppeaccardo Yes, of course: silly mistake by me. When you scroll, the column creates new cells, and those cells need to have their style set properly. Added an extra line in the cell factory which should make it work correctly.