# javaFX styling TableView

Tags: css, javafx-8

I'm trying to style my table.view.  How can I style this blue elements in tableview when the column is drag ? 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - Detect & highlight TableColumn being dragged onto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810408/javafx-detect-highlight-tablecolumn-being-dragged-onto)

Comment: i saw this post, but it dint help